# GTK+ 3 file dialog location entry?

Tags: linux, gnome, gtk

In GTK 2 I can click "type the file name" button to type in full path the entry. In GTK 3 there is only path bar, if I type something it redirect to search bar, which not what I want. Where is the location entry?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> is the usual shortcut for this. The location entry will also open if you press <kbd>.</kbd>, <kbd>~</kbd>, or <kbd>/</kbd>.

Comment: This doesn't work in all file dialogues. For example, it doesn't seem to work in Firefox's Save dialogue (FF 58).

Comment: OMFG THAT is one _hell_ of a stupid UX design!

Comment: Issue is tracked here: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/2443